Why do I get a “Texture usage flags mismatch” shader validation error when declaring an imageblock in a compute pass?
Suppose I want to draw a red rectangle onto my render target using a compute shader.
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[encoder setComputePipelineState:pipelineState];

simd_ushort2 position = simd_make_ushort2(100, 100);
simd_ushort2 size = simd_make_ushort2(50, 50);

[encoder setBytes:&position length:sizeof(position) atIndex:0];
[encoder setTexture:drawable.texture atIndex:0];

[encoder dispatchThreads:MTLSizeMake(size.x, size.y, 1)
   threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSizeMake(32, 32, 1)];

[encoder endEncoding];

#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void
Compute(ushort2 position_in_grid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
    constant ushort2 &position,
    texture2d<half, access::write> texture)
{
    texture.write(half4(1, 0, 0, 1), position_in_grid + position);
}

This works just fine:

Now, say for whatever reason I want to start using imageblocks in my compute kernel. First, I set the imageblock size on the CPU side:
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[encoder setComputePipelineState:pipelineState];

MTLSize threadgroupSize = MTLSizeMake(32, 32, 1);
[encoder setImageblockWidth:threadgroupSize.width
                     height:threadgroupSize.height];

simd_ushort2 position = simd_make_ushort2(100, 100);
simd_ushort2 size = simd_make_ushort2(50, 50);

[encoder setBytes:&position length:sizeof(position) atIndex:0];
[encoder setTexture:drawable.texture atIndex:0];

MTLSize gridSize = MTLSizeMake(size.x, size.y, 1);
[encoder dispatchThreads:gridSize threadsPerThreadgroup:threadgroupSize];

And then I update the compute kernel to simply declare the imageblock – note I never actually read from or write to it:
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct Foo
{
    int foo;
};

kernel void
Compute(ushort2 position_in_grid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
    constant ushort2 &position,
    texture2d<half, access::write> texture,
    imageblock<Foo> imageblock)
{
    texture.write(half4(1, 0, 0, 1), position_in_grid + position);
}

And now out of nowhere Metal’s shader validation starts complaining about mismatched texture usage flags:
2024-06-22 00:57:15.663132+1000 TextureUsage[80558:4539093] [GPUDebug] Texture usage flags mismatch executing kernel function "Compute" encoder: "1", dispatch: 0
2024-06-22 00:57:15.672004+1000 TextureUsage[80558:4539093] [GPUDebug] Texture usage flags mismatch executing kernel function "Compute" encoder: "1", dispatch: 0
2024-06-22 00:57:15.682422+1000 TextureUsage[80558:4539093] [GPUDebug] Texture usage flags mismatch executing kernel function "Compute" encoder: "1", dispatch: 0
2024-06-22 00:57:15.687587+1000 TextureUsage[80558:4539093] [GPUDebug] Texture usage flags mismatch executing kernel function "Compute" encoder: "1", dispatch: 0
2024-06-22 00:57:15.698106+1000 TextureUsage[80558:4539093] [GPUDebug] Texture usage flags mismatch executing kernel function "Compute" encoder: "1", dispatch: 0

The texture I’m writing to comes from a CAMetalDrawable whose associated CAMetalLayer has framebufferOnly set to NO. What am I missing?
